# How to know if a file is binary

Tags: file, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I know I can get a list of all files in directory and print their names with code:

```
(Directory working: '.') allFilesMatching: '*' 
   do: [:ff| ff name displayNl]
```

I can use `isDirectory` to find out if the file is a directory.

How can I find out if a file is binary and not text.

`isBinary` is mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual-base/gst-base.html) but it does not work:

```
(Directory working: '.') allFilesMatching: '*'
do: [ :ff |
    ((ff name), ': ') display.
    (ff isBinary) ifTrue: ['Binary file' displayNl.]
    ifFalse: [ 'Not a binary file.' displayNl.].
    infile close ].
```

The error is:

```
$ gst isBinary.st 
"Global garbage collection... done"
/home/abcd/myfile.bin: Object: RecursiveFileWrapper new "<0x7f6decdcdb30>" error: did not understand #isBinary
MessageNotUnderstood(Exception)>>signal (ExcHandling.st:254)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #isBinary (SysExcept.st:1448)
optimized [] in UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (isBinary.st:4)
[] in Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper(FilePath)>>filesMatching:do: (FilePath.st:903)
[] in Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo:prefixLength: (VFS.st:378)
[] in File>>namesDo: (File.st:589)
BlockClosure>>ensure: (BlkClosure.st:268)
File>>namesDo: (File.st:586)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo:prefixLength: (VFS.st:373)
[] in Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo:prefixLength: (VFS.st:382)
[] in File>>namesDo: (File.st:589)
BlockClosure>>ensure: (BlkClosure.st:268)
File>>namesDo: (File.st:586)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo:prefixLength: (VFS.st:373)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper>>namesDo: (VFS.st:396)
Kernel.RecursiveFileWrapper(FilePath)>>filesMatching:do: (FilePath.st:902)
File(FilePath)>>allFilesMatching:do: (FilePath.st:775)
Directory class>>allFilesMatching:do: (Directory.st:225)
UndefinedObject>>executeStatements (isBinary.st:1)
```

How can I determine if a file is binary?

Comment: All files are binary.

Comment: How to find if a file has readable text only?

Comment: Maybe by looking in the file for non-printable characters?  Or only printing files having certain extensions, like *.cs or *.txt?

Comment: How can I look for non-printable characters?

Comment: By writing code that opens the file, loops through each character one by one and compares it with a printable range.

Comment: The file extension approach is probably going to be better for you.

Comment: `#isBinary` is a method of `FileDescriptor` ("open file"), not `File` ("file properties").